# Spring bean customization with configurable properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean, property-placeholder

I have an xml bean configuration as follows:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="openJPADialect" />
    </bean>
```

I want to add a new property **defaultTimeout**, however I don't want to hard code it.

I want to instead put **some class** that will retrieve the value of this property from some in memory cache (doesn't matter from where actually)

I've heard and used before - **org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** However it retrieves values from a property file, which is not exactly what I need.

Could you please advise my direction?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to put instead of this property **some class** that will retrieve value of this property from some in memory cache (doesn't matter from where actually)

How about injecting your txManager into this **some class** and set the defaultTimeout there?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the com.typesafe.config library https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.typesafe/config/1.2.1. This allows you to load configuration files.

Use this library to create a bean of type config. Something like this. This is a java configuration, but could be adapted to an XML implementation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.your.package")
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public Config properties() throws Exception {
        String path = ""; // path to properties file
        Config conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(path));

        return conf;
    }
}
```

Then in your component classes, you can autowire the bean and use the properties stored in the in memory bean.

```
@Autowired
private Config properties;
...
properties.getString("your property key");
```